# Declaring asp.net control inside HTML markup

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to write something like this?

```
    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
     placeholder='<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFormName"></asp:Label>' type="text" required autofocus />
```

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself? If you get error, return here with a specific problem.

Comment: You'd have more success with an asp:Literal, personally I find it easier to render the whole tag as a HtmlGenericControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: let ASP.Net render extra attributes

You can use the native TextBox control :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"
             ID="name" 
             required="required" 
             autofocus="autofocus" 
             CssClass="form-control" 
             placeholder="myplaceholder" />
```

Extra attributes (ones that are not properties of the TextBox class), will be rendered as is:

Html result:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$name" 
       type="text"  
       id="MainContent_name"  
       class="form-control"  
       required="required"  
       autofocus="autofocus"  
       placeholder="myplaceholder" />
```

If the generated id must be explicit, you can add `CliendIDMode="Static"`:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             ID="name" 
             required="required" 
             autofocus="autofocus" 
             CssClass="form-control" 
             placeholder="myplaceholder" 
             ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Result:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$name"  
       type="text"  
       id="name"  
       class="form-control"  
       required="required"  
       autofocus="autofocus"  
       placeholder="myplaceholder" />
```

### Solution 2: write your own control

An even better approach is to extend the textbox class:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1.Controls
{
    public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
    {

        protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (AutoFocus) writer.AddAttribute("autofocus", "autofocus");
            if (Required) writer.AddAttribute("required", "required");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlaceHolder)) writer.AddAttribute("placeholder", PlaceHolder);

            base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        }

        public string PlaceHolder
        {
            get  {
                var obj = ViewState["PlaceHolder"];
                return obj != null ? (string)obj : default(string);
            }
            set { ViewState["PlaceHolder"] = value; }
        }

        public bool AutoFocus
        {
            get {
                var obj = ViewState["AutoFocus"];
                return obj != null ? (bool)obj : default(bool);
            }
            set { ViewState["AutoFocus"] = value; }
        }

        public bool Required
        {
            get {
                var obj = ViewState["Required"];
                return obj != null ? (bool)obj : default(bool);
            }
            set { ViewState["Required"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can register and use the control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="WebApplication1" TagPrefix="local" Namespace="WebApplication1.Controls" %>

....

<local:TextBoxEx runat="server" required="true" autofocus="true" PlaceHolder="my placeholder" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to assign some value to one of HTML element's properties?

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lblFormName" />
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder='<%# lblFormName.Value %>' ...
```

Then you pass `lblFormName.Value` from CodeBehind.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a single ASP.NET control in a pure HTML page. It must be a ASP.NET page (aspx) which is processed by the server.

Comment: Technically, an html page *can* be processed by asp.net. But it requires extra configuration.

Comment: Yes, but in any case the ASP.NET backend is required.